# What is files.wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I observed some sites like Tech Crunch and their Image URL is showing up as techcrunch11.files.wordpress.com/xyz If there is a way to upload images to Wordpress server, then my websites server load will reduce. Do you have any idea what is it? I couldn't find it on Google. I get redirected to wordpress.com when I try to access files.wordpress.com

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is the CDN service from [WordPress VIP](https://vip.wordpress.com/), a enterprise hosting service from Automattic.

Comment: Okay, thanx for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CDN / front-end caching: all scripts and stylesheets are served from our CDN. Images are served from our dedicated *.files.wordpress.com domain.

https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/caching/

That page should answer your question regarding the WordPress.com CDN. cybmeta correctly stated that it is for VIP WordPress members only.